# error checking a loop in r with webscraping

Tags: r, try-catch

I have a list of webpages that I want to check if a certain part of the website exists.

```
library(rvest)

links
[1] "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-22"
[2] "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-21"
[3] "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-20"
[4] "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-19"
[5] "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-18"
```

I've moved my code around a lot and can't seem to get anything to work.

```
newlist <- c()
for (i in 1:length(links)) {
  separate <- html(links[i])
  try(separate %>%
        html_nodes('div span') %>%
        .[[13]], silent=TRUE)
  newlist <- rbind(links[i],newlist)
}
```

The desired output would be the links that work (don't generate error).

```
[1] "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-22"
[2] "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-20"
```

So, essentially I have a list of links.  I'm having problems incorporating 'try' in R.  I want to loop through the links and try each one to see if the certain aspect of it exists - this is the part that I put in the try clause.  If it exists, then put that webpage in the 'newlist'.  If it doesn't exist then leave it out.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your example `separate` is just a character vector. You can't pipe that into `html_nodes`, you need a "session" object. you can create one with the `html()` function.

Comment: my fault completely - great catch.  i had had that in the earlier version and somehow left it out.  my current version doesn't leave out the links that don't work

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be to use a tryCatch :

```
links <- c("http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-22",
           "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-21",
           "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-20",
           "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-19",
           "http://www.stevel.com/?xid=2679644&dd=2015-01-18")

newlist <- c()
for(i in 1 : length(links)) 
{
  print(i)
  separate <- tryCatch(html(links[i]), error = function(e) NA)
  tryCatch((separate %>% html_nodes('div span') 
                     %>% .[[13]]), error = function(e) NA)
  
  newlist <- rbind(links[i], newlist)
}
```